# start with active menu item javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Hi I'm new and not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

I use Javascript that will decorate an active link after it's been clicked. 
Question is, how can I load the page with one of the menu items already active?

Example: http://moschalkx.nl/

Javascript code:

```
function hlite_menu(obj){
    var lnk=document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i in lnk){
        lnk[i].className=(lnk[i]===obj)?'menu_active':'menu_idle';
    }
}

function set_menu(){
    var lnk=document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i in lnk){
        lnk[i].className='menu_idle';
        lnk[i].onclick=function(){
            hlite_menu(this);
        }
    }
}

window.onload=set_menu;
```

CSS:

```
a.menu_idle {color:#333333; text-decoration:none;}
a.menu_active {color:#333333; text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited {color:#333333; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover {color:#333333; text-decoration:underline;}
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using? I can provide one if its asp.net

Answer (score 0):

You already have your `hlist_menu` function that sets a particular link to be active, so I would just call that from your `set_menu` function for whichever link is supposed to be active to begin with

```
function set_menu(){
    var lnk=document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i in lnk){
      lnk[i].className='menu_idle';lnk[i].onclick=function({hlite_menu(this);}}

      if (lnk[i] /* ??? how do you know whether this is the link to activeate up front? */ ) {
          hlist_menu(lnk[i]);
      }
    }
```

---

Also, this

```
lnk[i].onclick=function({hlite_menu(this);}}
```

can be simplified to just

```
lnk[i].onclick = hlite_menu;
```

assuming you change it to

```
function hlite_menu(){
    var lnk= document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('A');
    for(var i in lnk){
       lnk[i].className = (lnk[i] === this) ? 'menu_active':'menu_idle';
    }
}
```

Comment: hi adam i'm really not familiar with coding, can you explain to me how i can get this to work? i've added the if link part to the javascript, now do I need to point out the link that I want to be active upfront? maybe somewhere in the <a href line? or could you set up an example of how the complete code would look with java css and link setup? would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Mos - I'm not sure I follow. Yes, you need to point out which link is active up front.  Just add that logic to the menu set function where I have my comment.  I'm turning in, but if you have trouble, just post all your updated code and markup to a new question and something else will likely help you

Comment: ah so close! how would that logic look?